# Trying to call a method in another class to use in a IF statement

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to call a class when running an IF statement which will ask the user if they want to view the program in English or Spanish. The Spanish Code is in a different class and I want to call is so when/if the user chooses to view the program in Spanish and disregards the English code written below.

```
Error: Java cannot find symbol
symbol: method Spanish()
location: variable span of type source.Spanish
```

Below is my second class(that I want to call):

```
package source;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Spanish {
    public Spanish() {}
}
```

And below is how I am trying to call in my main class:

```
if (language.equals("Span")) {
    source.Spanish span = new source.Spanish();
    span.Spanish();
}
else {
   //More code.
}
```

My first time asking a question so I am sorry if the format isn't right or if the question has already been answered, I looked at a few of the past questions but no luck so far. Thank you :)

---

EDIT

```
package source;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class CashRegister {
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String registerfloat;
   String input;
   String name;
   String anotherTransaction;
   String item2;
   String choice;
   String language = "";
   double balance;
   double cost;
   double change = 0;
   double cash = 0;
   double amountRequired = 0;
   double totalAmount = 0;

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to the Cash Register.\n");

   while (true) {
       if (language.equals("Eng"))break;
       if (language.equals("Span"))break;

       else {
           System.out.println("Which language would you like to use? English (Eng) or Spanish (Span)?:");
           language = in.nextLine();
       }
   }

   if(language.equals("Span")) {
       source.Spanish span = new source.Spanish();
       span.Spanish();
   }
   else {

       System.out.print("Please enter cash register's float: $");
       registerfloat = in.nextLine();
       balance = Double.parseDouble(registerfloat);


       boolean loop = true;
       while (loop == true) {
           System.out.println("Do you wish to continue this transaction?: (Yes/No)");
           choice = in.nextLine();
           loop = false;
           switch (choice) {
               case "Yes":

                   System.out.print("Please enter the item's name:\n");
                   input = in.nextLine();
                   name = input;

                   System.out.print("Please enter the item's cost:");
                   input = in.nextLine();
                   cost = Double.parseDouble(input);


                   System.out.println("Do you wish to add another item?: Yes/No");
                   item2 = in.nextLine();

                   while (true) {
                       if (item2.equals("No"))
                           break;
                       else {
                           System.out.print("Please enter the item's name:\n");
                           input = in.nextLine();
                           name = input;

                           System.out.print("Please enter the item's cost:");
                           input = in.nextLine();
                           cost = Double.parseDouble(input);

                           System.out.println("Do you wish to add another item?: Yes/No");
                           item2 = in.nextLine();

                       }
                   }

                   Transaction trans = new Transaction(name, cost);

                   amountRequired = amountRequired + trans.getCost();
                   totalAmount = totalAmount + trans.getCost();

                   System.out.print("Please enter the cash amount tendered: $");
                   input = in.nextLine();
                   cash = cash + Double.parseDouble(input);
                   amountRequired = amountRequired - cash;

                   balance = balance + cash;
                   change = cash - totalAmount;

                   System.out.println("Amount of change required = " + change);
                   loop = true;
                   break;
               case "No":
                   balance = balance - change;
                   System.out.print("Balance of the Cash Register: $" + balance + "\n");

                   System.out.println("\nThank you for using the Cash Register!");

                   System.exit(0);
               default:
                   loop = true;
                   System.out.println("Wrong input, try again!");
                   break;
           }
       }
   }
```

}
}

Above is my entire code from CashRegister. "Spanish" has the EXACT same code except the print statements are in Spanish rather than English. Also, sorry if its hard to read or there is unnecessary stuff in there, its a group assignment and in early stages so is a bit of a mess. Cheers

**Update 2**

```
package source;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String registerfloat;
    String language = " ";
    double balance;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to the Cash Register.\n");

    System.out.print("Please enter cash register's float: $");
    registerfloat = in.nextLine();
    balance = Double.parseDouble(registerfloat);

    while (true) {
        if (language.equals("Eng")) break;
        if (language.equals("Span")) break;

        else {
            System.out.println("Which language would you like to use? English (Eng) or Spanish (Span)?:");
            language = in.nextLine();
        }
    }

    if (language.equals("Eng")) {
        source.CashRegister.CashRegister();
    }
    else {
        // trying to enter Spanish.register here but it does not even show as its not on the current branch.
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `public Spanish()` is a constructor, you can't call it like that.

Comment: How did you get this error "Main method not found"? Your code does not explain it.

Comment: Please try to post full code. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The statement `span.Spanish();` should have given you a compilation error (unless you've also defined a method `public void Spanish()` in class Spanish (as well as the constructor). You haven't shown us all the code so we can only guess.

Comment: If your "main" class `CashRegister` isn't compiling successfully, the "Main method not found..." error will probably go away once you have fixed whatever problem is preventing `CashRegister` from compiling.

Comment: what is the purpose of calling `span.Spanish();` ? Seriously, do you know that this is the constructor which you already called in the line above? You don't have to do anything else after it.

Comment: Do not add code to comments, edit your question instead. Also remove any error messages that are no longer relevant so that it's clear what your issue is.

Comment: I just tested the code again, and its no longer giving me the Main method error, so it was probably due to me adding the void in there and then running it like DodgyCodeException said. Its now giving me "java cannot find symbol" and symbol being method spanish. Full code and new error message posted now.

Comment: @AKSW he didn't call the constructor (that would not compile). But it is possible to define both a constructor and a void method of the same name in the same class. Perhaps that's what it was.

Comment: The answer below would make your program work. However, it's not good to have duplicated code. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it :)

I just replied to the answer, any idea why it might be doing that?

Comment: In your latest update, does calling `source.CashRegister.CashRegister();` work as expected? If it does then forget about git and branching, get all your code and copy it into a new place with the same directory structure and make sure you get the `Spanish` class to work properly. Resolving your branching issues is a separate problem but I must say I don't get it why you would need to work with different branches or even git at all at this stage as you said "it is in early stages". Keep it simple and address one problem at a time.

Comment: Nope, when I run my "RunClass/Starter", receiving this. Error: Main method not found in class source.CashRegister, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @Zubin you need to run RunClass, not CashRegister.

Comment: Nvm, my computer was acting up.

EDIT:
Ok so CashRegister is working fine. Just need to add the same class on the other branch and do the same for Spanish. @JoakimDanielson idk, we have been told to use git from the start and track commits and stuff.

Comment: Fair enough and it is not really my business but keep it simple (why branches?) so that you don't spend more time with tool issues than solving the programming task. Anyway, this is a java question so lets keep it at that.

Comment: Na all good. Its actually mainly based around git, programming is only half of the task if not less, so they want us to be using git at all times since that's what the course is about

Comment: @DodgyCodeException he called `source.Spanish span = new source.Spanish();` - for me this is calling a constructor, or not? `source` is just the package name...

Comment: @AKSW yes, that is calling a constructor. But the following statement, `span.Spanish();` is not calling a constructor but calling a normal method `public void Spanish()` (which is different to `public Spanish()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Spanish` class you have

```
public class Spanish {
    public Spanish() {}
}
```

but `public Spanish()` is not an ordinary method, it's a constructor that only can be called with the keyword `new` which you already do.

```
if (language.equals("Span")) {
    Spanish span = new Spanish();
    span.Spanish();
}
```

(I removed the package name since it isn't needed) So you need another method in your `Spanish` class that does the actual work.

The main problem though, apart from the fact that you have duplicated all the code, is that you are trying to do everything in the main() method of `CashRegister`

I would, for a start, create a simple starting class, lets call it `Starter` that ask the language question and then lets the `CashRegister` or `Spanish` class handle the main functionality.

```
class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Ask question about language as before

        if (language.equals("Span")) {
            Spanish.register();
        } else {
            CashRegister.register();
        }
    }
}
```

And then you implement a `register` method in both `CashRegister` and `Spanish` that contain the code after `else`, note that I made the method `static`

```
public class CashRegister {
    public static void register() {
        System.out.print("Please enter cash register's float: $");
        registerfloat = in.nextLine();
        balance = Double.parseDouble(registerfloat);
        //... rest of code
    }
}
```

This should get you started but there are many further improvements that can be done.

---

If you don't want to have a static method the `Starter` class needs to be modified as below but I think a static method makes more sense.

```
 if (language.equals("Span")) {
     Spanish spanish = new Spanish();
     spanish.register();
 } else {
     CashRegister cashRegister = new CashRegister();
     cashRegister.register();
 }
```

Comment: Ahhh ok. Makes sense.

It won't let me implement a register method with static, says 
    modifier static not allowed here
since its the top method so I removed static and when I try to call "CashRegister.CashRegister", it says java cannot find symbol because there is source at the start of CashRegister. 

Like this;

    source.CashRegister.CashRegister();

I know you said I don't need it but if I remove it, it says Cannot resolve symbol "CashRegister"

Comment: @Zubin Ok, I don't know your directory structure so add the package name back then. oops my declaration of the method is wrong, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Zubin make sure you define `public static register()` method **inside** the `class CashRegister { ... `

Comment: Ok so instead of using CashRegister.CashRegister, I changed it to source.CashRegister cr = new source.CashRegister and its not showing any error anymore however I need to break the code after "else" because my Spanish is class on another branch (using git) and keeps giving me an error so I was thinking I will break the code after else on both branches, but when I try to break it, it says "break outside switch or loop"

Comment: Let's leave git out of this , it only deters from the real question. There is no need to use `break` in the code. The main() method in `Starter` should end directly after the if/else as it is in my code, the rest of the code in your main method goes into `register()` in the two classes. Try to make it work together with `CashRegister` class first.